# Jupyter lab connection to github

Tags: git, github, data-science, jupyter-lab, git-extensions

[This shows tab of git without error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCq8p.jpg),[This shows Git tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83EJC.jpg) i have problem with jupyter lab, in Git tab there is no ‘Add  Remote Repository’ option ,which allow me to connect to github remote repo can anyone help ples

i tried to connect to remote bu using Git repository terminal in git menu but i couldn’t connect local repository to remote repository on my guthub account.

Comment: What about the `Manage Remote Repositories` option? Does that allow you to add remote repositories?

Comment: it takes old repo name and url then new tab appers request’s the new repo and new url, i can not connect to the remote repository.

Comment: Can you show how that looks and what the error is? Why don't you enter the URL of the actual repository instead of the old repository URL?

Comment: that’s what i do there is only one repository in mt github i want to connect to it i entered actual repository in old repository and then it required the new one ,all versions there is choice in git tab which is add remote repository that helps in that.

Comment: I added new photo to shows git tab in normal jupyter lab and what i get

Comment: Cross-posted [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/erorr-in-git-tab-in-jupyter-lab/17549/2?u=fomightez). Please, shadygharep always mention in every place you post all the other places you post the same question. As you can see @dan1st and myself pointed you at the same thing because we weren't aware of each other's reply. Thus you were wasting the time of people trying to help you. The other reason to link each and every cross-post is so that people with the same issue can find the answer. Keep in mind that you may be helping the future you find the solution later if it comes up again.

Comment: @Wayne so sorry my first time posting Question sorry for wasting your time

Comment: No problem. Just letting you know. Importantly, did you get your issue resolved or understand now how to get the equivalent of what you need from the newer offerings in the menu? Your comments suggest you haven't, but it seems the functionality is there but listed differently. So it seems your problem is different than you posted about here and maybe deserves a different post with a different title perhaps?

Comment: yes i manged to connect to git hub by terminal , i will change title okay.